# php_excel07- how to fix min heigth and mak to grow height based on the contents of a cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have to Export data to xlsx, where the exported file should be in a pre defined format. Becoz of these i am using "PHPexcel". And i created a template of some format with each row with some specified height.

Actually in each cell i will be writing the data dynamically. so if the text is larger, then the row height in not increased.

So is ther anyway so tat row height is increased to fit the cell text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set a row to autofit:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(10)->setAutoSize(true);
```

And then set the individual cells to allow wrapping

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A10:D10')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Comment: Hi Mark,how to specify the min height of row. For Ex if i don hav any data in all the cells in the row, in this case it should have some specified height. i mean each row shld hav min heigth.

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't allow you to specify a minimum height... only an absolute height, or autofit

Comment: in latest version of PhpExcell the method setAutoSize(true) does not exist in class PHPExcel_Worksheet_RowDimension or in class PHPExcel_Worksheet_Dimension, so $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(10)->setAutoSize(true); crashes