# php_excel07- How to make grow the height of cell based on cell data(xls)

Tags: php, phpexcel

In my application i need to export to `xls` file in a predefined format.

so I just integrated `php_excel2007`. I am using one template with a predefined format.

**The problem** here is the cell data may change dynamically. if data is much bigger than cell height then data is collapsing.

So is ther anyway to increase the height of cell based on content of the cell(in XLX not xlsx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once ROOT.'/PHPExcel.php';

function down($details)
{
    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load(ROOT."/templates/project_report1.xls");

    // Set properties
    $p_i=5;$alpa="B";$row_no=5;$mil="";$d_cel="B";
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()
                ->setCellValue('K1', $details['report_details']['cur_time']);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()
                ->setCellValue('C2', 'REPORT START DATE:'.$details['report_details']['start_date'])
                ->setCellValue('H2', $details['report_details']['details'])
                ->setCellValue('C3', 'SHOWING:'.$details['report_details']['showing']);
    foreach($details as $p_name=>$date){
        //thisis to display date at the top 
        foreach($date as $p1=>$m_name1){
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($d_cel.'4', $p1);$d_cel++;//to display date in the top
        }
        break;
    }

    foreach($details as $p_name=>$date){
        if($p_name=="report_details")break;
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$p_i, $p_name);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->duplicateStyle( $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A5'), 'A'.$p_i );
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A'.$p_i)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);    

        foreach($date as $p=>$m_name){
            $mil=$tic=$st=" ";

            foreach($m_name as $name=>$val){

            if($name=="milestone")
            foreach($val as $in_det=>$det){
                if($det && isset($det['start_date']))
                    $mil.=$det['name']."\n".$det['start_date']."\n";
                else
                    $mil.=$det['name'];
            }
            if($name=="ticket")
                foreach($val as $in_det=>$det){                             
                    if($det)
                        $tic.=$det['name']." ".$det['start_date']."\n";
                }
            if($name=="task")
                foreach($val as $in_det=>$det){
                    if($det)
                        $st.=$det['name']." ".$det['start_date']."\n";
                }
            }
            $summary=$mil.$tic.$st;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->duplicateStyle( $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B5'), $alpa.$p_i );
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getRowDimension($p_i)->setRowHeight();
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getStyle('A'.$p_i.':'.'M'.$p_i)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle($alpa.$p_i)->getFont()->setSize(5);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($alpa.$p_i, $summary);
            $alpa++;
        }
        $alpa="B";
        $p_i++;
    }
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Report');
    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="project_report.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: It would be useful to highlight just the code where you make grow the height of cell based on cell data...

Answer (score 5):

The only way is as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881623/php-excel07-how-to-fix-min-heigth-and-mak-to-grow-height-based-on-the-contents-o) to your previous question on this topic: setting the row height to autofit, and the cell alignment to wrap. This should work the same way, whether you use the Excel5 Writer or the Excel2007 Writer.

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set some long string values in some cells
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue("This is a large block of text,\ncomprising several lines,\nthat will be set to autofit.");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A2')->setValue("This is a large block of text that will NOT be set to autofit.");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->setValue("This is another large block of text without any line breaks, that will be set to autofit.");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A3')->setValue("This is another large block of text,\ncomprising several lines,\nthat will be set to autofit.");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A4')->setValue("This is another large block of text without any line breaks, that will be set to autofit but not wrap.");
// Fix the column width to a reasonable size
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(30);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);
//  Set text wrap for cells A1 and B1. This forces the text to wrap, but doesn't adjust the height of the row
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
// Set rows 1, 3 and 4 to autofit the height to the size of text
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(3)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(4)->setRowHeight(-1);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('testAutoHeight.xls');
```

**EDIT**

Added comments to the code sample to explain what each called method actually does

Comment: I've tried this but if I open the file in LibreOffice Calc, the row height is not set. Any idea what could be wrong? Here's a link to [my code](https://gist.github.com/mikehaertl/280455b503dc8c4ccddd)

Comment: Sorry, i tried this but it has no effect. The height of the row does not adapt to text content height :(

Comment: @AndreiDiaconescu - the code I quoted works, if you think otherwise then provide specifics..... "it don't work" is not acceptable as an error report

Comment: the function call $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1); does not work; i am testing it now, with latest version of PhpExcel; It does not adapt the height of the line to fit the height of the text. I mention i test this for XLS not XLSX

Comment: Have you set text wrap? And do you have new lines in your cell content? Simply specifying that single line of code doesn't cause the row height to adjust without the additional settings

Comment: @AndreiDiaconescu - Take a look at row 10 (cell A10) in [Examples/01simple.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simple.php) that has an

Comment: thank you. Yes i am using textWrap. I do not have new lines in cell content. What i was looking for is the same functionality that Excel or Open Office has: double clicking on the separation line between 2 rows auto adjust the height of the row above.

Answer (score 1):

setRowHeight to -1 for make auto height (based on cell data)

```
// auto-size on row 1

$objWorksheet->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(-1);
```

Comment: Sorry, i tried this but it has no effect. The height of the row does not adapt to text content height :(

Comment: @AndreiDiaconescu - the code I quoted works, if you think otherwise then provide specifics..... "it don't work" is not acceptable as an error report

Comment: the function call $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1); does not work; i am testing it now, with latest version of PhpExcel; It does not adapt the height of the line to fit the height of the text.  I mention i test this for XLS not XLSX