# php_excel: Customize the heigth row

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHP_excel to export to xlsx. where im using template which has each row with a fixed height  of 48. But some times the text within the cell is increases, during which row height doesn't grow even if i use wraptext().So is there any possible way to grow the height of row only in case it has more text.

Comment: Do you ask every single problem in different questions? Why don't you merge them into a single one?

Comment: Sandeep - I have already answered this exact question for you twice already this week. I refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913926/php-excel07-how-to-make-grow-the-height-of-cell-based-on-cell-dataxls/3914102#3914102 for my previous answer... but I will not actually modify your code for you. Use both wraptext for the cell **and** autofit height for the row

Comment: I've now added some comments in the code example for the previous linked answer to this question to try and demonstrate the different combinations of wrapText and autofit height, for cells containing text with and without line breaks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are trying to apply the wraptext() only to the line you expect to grow up in height?

I solved a similar problem by applying the behaviour I desired as default style for worksheet, which you set with:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

You can find all the info in more detail in the PHPExcel [Developer Documentation](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/26478#DownloadId=145938).

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Giovanni