# PHPExcel setRowHeight('-1') don't work

Tags: phpexcel

I have some cells with text, in which strings are transferred by words.
I need to set 'auto height' to the rows, but it does not work.

Below is my code:

```
$this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight('-1');
```

Comment: Did you try this ? $excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);

Comment: Refer this - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054444/how-to-set-auto-height-in-phpexcel

Comment: Yes, I have tryed this but it exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Set the cell styles to wrap, otherwise the cell height will just be the height of a single line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881623/php-excel07-how-to-fix-min-heigth-and-mak-to-grow-height-based-on-the-contents